# About the number of moderation flags

Tags: support, flagging, rate-limiting

I have looked on the website for quite some time now, and I still haven't find how the number of moderation flags available is computed.

I think  at first I had $10$ of them, but then after a little while, I starting to have some more.

Is there an explicite formula which gives that number ?

It must take in account the number of successful flags distributed.

Comment: See also [How many flags does a user have per day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149659/how-many-flags-does-a-user-have-per-day) and [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits) on meta.SE.

Comment: Thank you, perfect link.